# ServletException in:/layouts/menu.jsp null' in one portion of jsp page where redirect link is there

Tags: java, struts-1, apache-tiles, servletexception

There is a java struts 1.1 web application developed using java 4 and which is now being upgraded to openjdk 8. While running the application I am getting this servlet exception in the UI screen in one portion which consists of a link to different jsp page. How to fix this issue?

[ServletException in:/layouts/menu.jsp] null'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I think it's getting hung up somewhere in your Action class, as soon as you enter the entry point of your Action class. Place some system outs to the console and check how far you can get with it. Then if you don't see your next system  out, then that's where the issue may be hanging around.